# How does Donate work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Donate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDonate%5d) is a pretty useful yet useless card. I have two questions about it.

> *Target player gains control of target permanent you control.*

Does this mean the "target permanent you want your opponent to control" has to be on the battlefield? And also, when your opponent takes control of that card, does it go into their control (command) on the battlefield? Or does it go into their hand?

Comment: Psst! Hey buddy:
http://magiccards.info/ai/en/58.html
http://magiccards.info/ia/en/79.html
your opponent may want some of these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target permanent you control refers to a card on the battlefield. So yes it has to be on the battlefield and it would stay on the battlefield when it comes under their control.

Answer (score 2):

When a card says "target permanent", it means a permanent on the battlefield. This is specified in [rule 109.2](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Object):

> If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn't include the word "card," "spell," "source," or "scheme," it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

When a card says that a player "gains control" of a permanent, it means that the permanent's controller changes from the player that currently controls it to the new player. It doesn't change anything else about the permanent, like counters or whether it's tapped.

Comment: I think all you need here is "110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield." since Donate explicitly says "permanent", not just a card type.

Comment: You're probably right. The rule I quoted if the right one for most of these sorts of questions, but that one's probably better here.